# How to get summary value from java program to php script?

Tags: java, php, mysql, encoding

I get string *Operacinės sitemos* from mysql using php script. But when I try to send this value again to php script and get other values I am getting null. I think problem might be with php script which gets non-english characters. Am I missing something?

**Java code:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.single_course_layout);

Intent in = getIntent();
courseName = in.getStringExtra("fullname");
firstname = in.getStringExtra("firstname");
lastname = in.getStringExtra("lastname");

TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
label.setText(courseName);
String summary = null;
TextView summaryContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summary);


ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cname",""+courseName));
InputStream is = null; 
String result = null;
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("********");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"ISO-8859-10"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                System.out.println(line);
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

try{
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for(int ii=0;ii<jArray.length();ii++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(ii);
        summary = json_data.getString("summary");
 }
summaryContent.setText(summary);
} catch(JSONException e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}

};
```

**PHP script:**

```
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","***","*****");
    mysql_select_db("*******");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
    $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cname']);

    $q=mysql_query("SELECT mdl_course.summary FROM mdl_course WHERE mdl_course.fullname = '$fullname'");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            $output[]=$e;

    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

**Eddited**

This php code works fine. I can see the needed output. But why the script above doesn't work?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","*******","*********");
mysql_select_db("************");
$fullname = 'Operacinės sistemos';
$q=mysql_query("SELECT mdl_course.summary FROM mdl_course WHERE mdl_course.fullname = '$fullname'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` would be better than `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Answer (score 0):

> How to send utf-8_lithuanian_ci to php script?

That's very simple. `utf-8_lithuanian_ci` is a collation, so the moment you have data with an order of that collation, it's already done - you only need to pass that data. Collation can only be applied when sorting, so as the data is already sorted when you pass it, there is nothing else you need to do.

If you ask about the encoding, it can not be strictly said. It's common you use the UTF-8 encoding here (as the collation is UTF-8 based), however, technically you can use any different character-encoding as well and as you have not specified which one, it remains imprecise.

Additionally, the usage of [`SET NAMES utf8`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) within PHP is not recommended *and* the usage of the whole mysql extension is discouraged.

Comment: Do you mean this? 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-10"),8);

Comment: Try with replacing ISO-... with UTF-8. Just a quick guess, test quickly if this solves your issue, otherwise you'll need to do the debugging more precise (uhm, do actual debugging, not guessing, guessing is ok for a two-minute fix, but if it takes longer, stop guessing).

Comment: No it did not helped. I still can't get summary value

Comment: @LTnewbie: I edited the question of your title, to it's more clear that this about a concrete value instead of the collation.